# VB.Net making extension method without polluting global namespace?

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

To write a extension method in vb.net you have to put them in a Module, all methods defined in a module get added to the global namespace.

Is there any way to remove the methods from the global namespace so they only are used as extension method or if you actually write the module name first?

**Example**

TypeExtensionMethods.vb:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module TypeExtensionMethods
    Private ReadOnly numericTypes As TypeCode() = {
        TypeCode.Byte, TypeCode.SByte, TypeCode.UInt16,
        TypeCode.UInt32, TypeCode.UInt64, TypeCode.Int16,
        TypeCode.Int32, TypeCode.Int64, TypeCode.Decimal,
        TypeCode.Double, TypeCode.Single}

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsNumber(type As Type) As Boolean
        Dim currentTypeCode As TypeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(type)
        Return currentTypeCode.IsNumber()
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsNumber(type As TypeCode) As Boolean
        Return numericTypes.Any(Function(tc) tc = type)
    End Function
End Module
```

Class1.vb:

```
Class Class1

    Sub Main(value as Object)
        'This should work
        dim result1 as Boolean = value.GetType().IsNumber()
        'This should work
        dim result2 as Boolean = TypeExtensionMethods.IsNumber(value.GetType())
        'This should not work, the method IsNumber is polluting as it can be called without specifying where its defined.
        dim result3 as Boolean = IsNumber(value.GetType())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am a little confused. What do you mean by "they only are used as extension method"? And if you have to profix the module name, what do you use an extension method at all? You seem to call the method directly. From what you asked I think extension method are the wrong approach. Instead you could sub-class the type in question an add the method you want. That way you could cast your original type to the subclassed type and call the method. Let me know if that is an option and if you want som example code.

Comment: @Sascha if you define a method in a module you can just call it by its name with out using it as a extension method or using the name of the module, so lets say i define a Extension Method `IsNumeric` now its in the global namespace and can be used `IsNumeric(value....)` now lets say you have 100 extension methods now they are all polluting the global namespace... sub classing is no solution, i want extension methods but i dont want them in my global namespace..

Comment: @Sascha Sub classing doesn't work lets say you get a string from `FileInfo.FullName` first of `string` is `sealed` so i can't inherit it secondly even if i could inherit it i could not cast that specific string to my own type as i didn't create the string in the first place, and thirdly if i have to cast every time i need to run a method i pollute my code with alot of ugly casting...

Comment: Just for a better understanding: could you post a small example of one of your extension methods? And could you explain, what "polluting" really means to you? Is it just that you don't want it to show up in the intellisense menues?

Comment: [Put extension methods into their own namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/03/10/extension-methods-best-practices-extension-methods-part-6.aspx)

Comment: It becomes clear that this nothing to do with extension methods; It's just about defining namespaces and importing namespaces.

Comment: @Abhitalks that makes it some what better but as soon as you import the namespace you get those ugly methods again..

Comment: @TomBlodget no this has nothing to do with extension methods to do it has to do how methods inside modules are handled but in vb.net you can only define your extension methods in modules..

Comment: @Peter: It's same as in C#. The modules in VB.Net equate to public static classes in C# and on compilation the modules actually get converted to static classes. In VB.Net extensions methods are allowed only in a module (*because there are no shared classes in VB.Net*). This is something you will have to live with, as this is the requirement of extension methods. You need to import the namespace in order to use them. The fact that extension methods extend the type is what necessitates their invocation without a fully qualified name. Keeping them in a separate namespace is the best you could do.

Comment: @Abhitalks well yes I guess ill have to live with it but one thing is wrong with your statment, c# does not have a Global namespace so its not 100% the same in C#...

Comment: Ideas probably not worth doing… If you can live with a separate project for the extension methods, make it a C# project. If that won't do and you can live with a separate VB project outside the solution, hack a rebuild process for the assembly to remove the StandardModule attribute from the module.(Ironically, there is a HideModuleName attribute that does the opposite of what you want: It makes your result2 case not compile.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not possible!